# how to delete a specific row in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.In my view page I am showing the data  from database in a table where I have two anchor tags for update and delete. I want to delete a specific row from database through id.

my view page is

```
 <?php foreach($query as $row){ ?>
 <tr>
 <td><?php echo $row->name  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row->testi  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo anchor('textarea/delete_row', 'DELETE', 'id="$row->id"'); ?></td>
  <td><a href="#ajax-modal2" data-id="delete[]" role="button" class="Delete" data-toggle="modal" onClick="confirm_delete()"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

my controller page is

```
function delete_row()
{

   $this->load->model('mod1');
   $this->mod1->row_delete();
   redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
}
```

and my model page is

```
 function row_delete()
  {

      $this->db->where('id', $id);
      $this->db->delete('testimonials'); 
  }
```

I want to delete the row by catching the respective id. Please dont be harsh. thank you

Comment: YOU have to pass the $id to delete_row in your model

Answer (score 24):

You are using an `$id` variable in your model, but your are plucking it from nowhere. You need to pass the `$id` variable from your controller to your model.

## Controller

Lets pass the $id to the model via a parameter of the `row_delete()` method.

```
function delete_row()
{
   $this->load->model('mod1');

   // Pass the $id to the row_delete() method
   $this->mod1->row_delete($id);


   redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
}
```

## Model

Add the $id to the Model methods parameters.

```
function row_delete($id)
{
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->delete('testimonials'); 
}
```

The problem now is that your passing the `$id` variable from your controller, but it's not declared anywhere in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

a simple way:

in view(pass the id value):

```
<td><?php echo anchor('textarea/delete_row?id='.$row->id, 'DELETE', 'id="$row->id"'); ?></td>
```

in controller(receive the id):

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');
$this->load->model('mod1');
$this->mod1->row_delete($id);
```

in model(get the passed args):

```
function row_delete($id){}
```

Actually, you should use the ajax to POST the id value to controller and delete the row, not the GET.

Comment: first of all thank u sir. one more thing do i need to add nything extra inside model function row_delete or should i remain the same code inside?

Comment: you are welcome, just put my code in yours. it's a fast way to meet demand, but not the best way. GET is a idempotent method, POST are not. So we use GET fetch the data, and POST modify the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
**multiple delete not working**

function delete_selection() 
{
        $id_array = array();
        $selection = $this->input->post("selection", TRUE);
        $id_array = explode("|", $selection);

        foreach ($id_array as $item):
            if ($item != ''):
                //DELETE ROW
                $this->db->where('entry_id', $item);
                $this->db->delete('helpline_entry');
            endif;
        endforeach;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It will come in the url so you can get it by two ways.
**Fist one**

```
<td><?php echo anchor('textarea/delete_row', 'DELETE', 'id="$row->id"'); ?></td>
$id = $this->input->get('id');
```

**2nd one.**

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

But in the second method you have to count the no. of segments in the url that on which no. your id come. 2,3,4 etc. then you have to pass. then in the ();

Answer (score 1):

**My controller**

```
public function delete_category()   //Created a controller class //
    {      
         $this->load->model('Managecat'); //Load model Managecat here 
         $id=$this->input->get('id');     //  get the requested in a variable
         $sql_del=$this->Managecat->deleteRecord($id); //send the parameter $id in Managecat  there I have created a function name deleteRecord

         if($sql_del){

               $data['success'] = "Category Have been deleted Successfully!!";  //success message goes here 

         }

    }
```

**My Model**

```
public function deleteRecord($id) {

    $this->db->where('cat_id', $id);
    $del=$this->db->delete('category');   
    return $del;

}
```